# The old message is shown only when I send new message or refresh the page in my chatting application

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, chat

I am making a chatting application in Php. The problem I am facing is that only when I send 2nd message then 1st message appears. For example if I have to see 4th sent message then I have to send 5 th message or refresh the page. Please help to find where the problem is. Simlified code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Chatting project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <header>
  <h1><span>Chatting project</span></h1>
  </header>
  <div id="shouts">
      <ul>

    <!--   Insert MySQL datbase into HTML     -->
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
    $shouts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    ?>

    <!--   Insert MySQL datbase into HTML     -->
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shouts)) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $row['name']; ?>: <?php echo $row['shout']; ?> [<?php echo $row['date']; ?>]</li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>
      <form action="index.php" method="post">

      <label>Shout Text: </label>
      <input type="text" name="shout" placeholder="Enter your message here">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SHOUT!" >
    </form>

<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES       `('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";`
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>   


</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it better if you use AJAX?

Comment: I think my solution below should help, you are `SELECTING` data before you put a new row to your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your code that you are `INSERTING` after `SELECTING` from SQL. Those lines:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES       `('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";`
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Should be before `SELECT` lines:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
$shouts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
```

So it will be like:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES `('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";`
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
$shouts = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

In your case you are fetching data before you put a new one to your database, so in a moment you `SELECT` from database there is no new row yet.

Comment: NO brother its not working. The same issue is there.@Karol Gasienica

Comment: I can't post whole of the code in 1 comment..so see 2nd too

Comment: <!--   Insert MySQL datbase into HTML     -->
               <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
        
$shouts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>

Comment: <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
$shouts = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// close connection

mysqli_close($link);
?>

Comment: The last part of code:
          <form action="index.php" method="post">
          
          <label>Shout Text: </label>
          <input type="text" name="shout" placeholder="Enter your message here">
          <input type="submit" name="save" id="submit" value="SHOUT!" >
        </form>

Comment: You still have `INSERT` after `SELECT`, how do you want to select a row which don't exist yet? `INSERT` need to be first to insert a new row.

Comment: And you can edit your code in first post and write actual one.